# safeAreaLayoutGuide not work for systemLayoutSizeFittingSize

Tags: ios, ios11, safearealayoutguide

I using safe area in iOS 11 like that:

[code picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibS9V.png)

```
/** mainTableView **/
[self.view addSubview:self.mainTableView];
[self.mainTableView makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.left.equalTo(self.view.left);
    make.right.equalTo(self.view.right);
    if (@available(iOS 11.0,*)) {
        self.mainTableViewTop = make.top.equalTo(self.view.mas_safeAreaLayoutGuideTop).offset(navHeight).priorityLow();
        self.mainTableViewBottom = make.bottom.equalTo(self.view.mas_safeAreaLayoutGuideBottom).offset(0).priorityLow();
    }else{
        self.mainTableViewTop = make.top.equalTo(self.view.top).offset(navHeight + iAStatusHeight).priorityLow();
        self.mainTableViewBottom = make.bottom.equalTo(self.view.bottom).offset(-tabHeight);
    }
}];
```

then run in iPhone X

[iPhone X layout picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fkjza.png)

so , where is the top constraint and bottom constraint ?

It's no problem in adapter . but when I want to geting the view's height.It will be always return 0.

like that :

I want to calculate tableview's height in my view :

[tableview height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OT3vO.png)

```
[self.mainTableView reloadData];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
    if ([self isShowRefreshFooter]) {
        CGFloat mainTableHeight = [self.mainTableView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
        CGFloat contentHeight = self.mainTableView.contentSize.height;
        if (contentHeight < mainTableHeight) {
            self.reFreshFooter.hidden = YES;
        }else{
            self.reFreshFooter.hidden = YES;
        }
    }
});
```

but mainTableHeight always return 0

[return 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvujr.png)

please give me some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix that in follow:

step 1:

```
_detailTableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

step 2:

```
[bgView addSubview:self.detailTableView];
[self.detailTableView makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.top.equalTo(titleLabel.bottom).offset(16).priorityHigh();
    make.left.equalTo(bgView.left).offset(0);
    make.right.equalTo(bgView.right).offset(0);
    make.bottom.equalTo(bgView.bottom).offset(0);
    make.height.equalTo(100).priorityHigh();
}];

[self.detailTableView reloadData];
[self.detailTableView layoutIfNeeded];
CGFloat contentHeight = self.detailTableView.contentSize.height;
[self.detailTableView updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.height.equalTo(contentHeight).priorityHigh();
}];
```